# Bash script to create a folder structure

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, script

I'm trying to write a Bash script to automate a recurring task, namely the creation of a structure of folders, where some of them should be numbered (To be more specific, this is meant to archive some TV series that I've converted from DVD in a folder structure easily understandable by the Kodi media player)

A first try was like this:

```
echo "Insert the title of the series"
read title

mkdir $title
mkdir $title/extrafanart
mkdir $title/themes
mkdir $title/videoextras

for num in {1..3}
do
  mkdir $title/"Season $num"
done
```

This correctly creates the following structure, in example

```
Star Trek
Star Trek\extrafanart
Star Trek\Season 1
Star Trek\Season 2
Star Trek\Season 3
Star Trek\themes
Star Trek\videoextras
```

which is precisely what I needed. But, as you can probably see, there is a major drawback in this script: the total number of season folders is fixed, and not dynamically chosen every time the script is run. So I've tried to modify it as follows

```
echo "Insert the title of the series"
read title
echo "Insert the number of seasons"
read seasons

mkdir $title
mkdir $title/extrafanart
mkdir $title/themes
mkdir $title/videoextras

for num in {1..$seasons}
do
  mkdir $title/"Season $num"
done
```

This time, the result is not exactly what I was expecting, this is what I get

```
Star Trek
Star Trek\extrafanart
Star Trek\Season {1..3}
Star Trek\themes
Star Trek\videoextras
```

which is NOT what I need.

I guess that the problem is in the first line of the `for` loop, where the brace expansion is read by the shell as a string and not as an expression to evaluate. Am I right?

What is wrong and how can I correct this script?

Comment: Parameter expansion happens after brace expansion, so `{1..$seasons}` is not a valid brace expansion and it is treated literally.

Comment: Actually, the script as given shouldn't work right due to spaces etc in the show titles. You really should have double-quotes around variable references including `$title` (e.g. `mkdir "$title"` and `mkdir "$title/Season $num"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
num=1
while [ $num -le $seasons ]; do
  mkdir $title/"Season $num"
  num=$[ $num + 1 ]
done
```

**Explanation**

We're using the [ test operator and $[ evaluation operator (they look alike, but are completely different). `[ $num -le $seasons ]` tests if $num is **L**ess or **E**qual than $seasons; `$[ $num + 1 ]` adds one to the numerical value of $num and assigns it back to $num.

For information about the test operator, type `help test` in your bash shell. The evaluation operator is explained in the bash manual (`man bash`, be warned, it's long). You can also use it to subtract, multiply, divide, etc.

Comment: Thanks, it worked now. Would you be so kind to explain this to me (or to point me to some online resource), so I can better understand what I've done? In particular, what are the `-le` parameters standing for?

Comment: Added an explanation.